# Firefox not working with Custom Tabs Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs, firefox-android

My application opens specific url from app via CustomTabs.

Url is of local server with self signed certificate, so when i open url with Firefox it shows 'Untrusted Connection' with options 'Visit site' and 'Add permanent exception', but neither of buttons works with Firefox (i.e not redirecting to website nor adding exception). Screenshot attached.[Screen Shot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzSx5.jpg)

It works fine with Chrome,Opera,UC and other default browsers.

Comment: Are the buttons clickable? And does the untrusted connection page appear for all the other browsers?

Comment: @JoeMuller Yes buttons are clickable but no further redirection happens. Yes, untrusted connection page appears for all other browser but on clicking possible options, browser redirecting to actual site with exception or understanding the risk.

Comment: I retested this again today and I can only confirm it's broken :( even though as far as in July I tested redirects on firefox with custom tabs and it worked